# Why does PHP takes 10x more memory with CLI than Web?

Tags: php, memory, command-line-interface

I'm using a framework with a big project and I realized that job commands (cron, jobs, ...) with CLI generated more alerts than web access.

I was investigating and I realized it's nothing to do with the framework, but PHP it self.

Let's take an empty dir and with composer I add, let's say, 20 libraries.

If I do a simple PHP with this line:

```
require __DIR__ . 'vendor/autoload.php'; 
exit(memory_get_usage()/1024/1024)
```

a) if I run through CLI, it takes 8.2 Mb
b) if I run through web, it takes 0.4 Mb

Why is that?

This basic example, extrapolated to a project, generates CLI commands using 30Mb or 40Mb, instead of the 3/4 Mb that web pages use.

Comment: Web uses opcache or JIT buffer. So if it ran once it can be held in a cache.

Comment: is any way to do the same with CLI? because cronjobs runs every minute ;-)

Comment: You could simply curl them :D Or make them working like a worker forever and not respawning all the time.

Comment: what do you mean ? i dont understand ... curl the vendor libraries ? wtf ? :-D

Comment: Make the script available via web. Secure with a key for example and make cron job calling the script with curl. What else would you curl? :)

Comment: that's insane (and clever too, but insane XD ) ... cron jobs are done for something ... not for cheating them ... i have tons of cronjobs commands setup in the framework and it's insane to move all cron logic outside to call things via web ... it has to be other way to solve the original question problem

Comment: Simplest solution: Get enough RAM. Do you even run into memory issues? As I said, use workers! You should use queues. Your architecture is not optimized, then.

Comment: All optimization problems in the world solved: "buy bigger machines"

Comment: Easy, but **use workers and queues**.